# What are the blue lines in a wireframe

Tags: wireframe

so, I've been working on a Blender file for a while, and I forgot what I did to make the wires turn dark blue, like so:

[image: screenshot]

Anyone knows what this means?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It appears that you have enabled *show weights* under *mesh display*.

You can disable this in the properties panel while in *edit mode* by pressing <kbd>N</kbd> to open the properties panel, and locating *Mesh Display* and then unchecking the option.

Other blue lines can also be caused by having the *sharp* box ticked. Uncheck this if necessary too.

[image]